# Meaning of "EC" in x86 disassembly

Tags: x86, intel-syntax

I am trying to disassemble Hex "8B EC". The disassembler gives me `mov ebp, esp`

- "8B" - `MOV` Instruction;
- "EC" - ???;

How disassembler know that "EC" is `ebp, esp`?

Comment: That's called the "ModR/M" byte. It's documented in Volume 2A of [Intel's Architecture Manual](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html). See if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829602/hex-values-of-registers-x86?lq=1) helps.

Comment: The disassembler knows in exactly the same way as the CPU executing it knows - that byte contains two 3-bit register codes and a 2-bit addressing mode packed into it in some manner as defined by the architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EC` is not specifically `ebp, esp`, it could mean various things depending on the opcode in front of it.

It could mean

- `/5 esp` (for example, in `83 EC 10  sub esp, 16`)
- `esp, ebp` (for example, in `89 EC   mov esp, ebp`)
- `ebp, esp` (for example, in `8B EC   mov ebp, esp`)
- `ah, ch` (for example, in `00 EC     add ah, ch`)
- `ch, ah` (for example, in `02 EC     add ch, ah`)
- `mm5, mm4` (for example in `0F FC EC paddb mm5, mm4`)
- `xmm5, xmm4` (for example in `66 0F FC EC paddb xmm5, xmm4`)
- `sp, gs` (for example in `8C EC      mov sp, gs`)
- `gs, sp` (for example in `8E EC      mov gs, sp`)
- `st, st(4)` (for example in `DB EC   fucomi st, st(4)`)
- `st(4), st` (for example in `DC EC   fsub st(4), st`)

There are actually even more. So, I recommend against assigning too much meaning to a ModRM in isolation, it's really important what opcode it goes with (and prefixes).